# Field value getting deleted after updating trhough Process Builder workflow

Tags: process-builder, flow, field-update

We have a Process builder workflow which updates a field to a record ID on creation of a X record. However, the field value gets deleted with a time gap of a min or at the same time. When checked the record history, it is clearly showing as @16: 42 Field value updated to ID and @16:43 Deleted the field value. As the Occurrence of this  error is very rare, I say out of 40 times once or twice, not able to figure it out how its getting deleted. Has anybody faced the same issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you confirm that there are no other workflows or triggers on this object/related objects that does this?  You may want to double check this, by using debug logs.  At this specific update, check debug logs to see if there are any other workflows/triggers being fired.

Comment: We have many workflows and triggers on the same object. However, none of them have an action delete this value.

Comment: Can you add field history tracking to the field, that might help get some more clues.

Comment: @gorav Added field history tracking and its clearly showing the history as 
-16: 42 Field value updated to ID  
- 16:43 'X' person deleted the field value
I confirm that none of them doing it manually, happening in the system by itself. Any thoughts, however will be investigating and post it if I find it.

Comment: Is user for 16:42 update same as user for 16:43 delete?

Comment: @gorav Yes, its the same person.

Comment: Could it be an order of operations issue?  W multiple workflows and triggers it's hard to say, but sometimes when I find quirky  behavior, it's due to the non determinative order of operations on field updates, trigger methods, etc.  One thought is that You could create a simple workflow rule to notify you when this scenario happens, as an initial step in debugging.

Comment: Yes this is due to one of the triggers on the object. We have few triggers installed by Managed package and one of them is deleting this value. We reported this and they have given us a workaround to overcome this. Thanks all for your help!!